# Try - except not displaying Exception error message

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-7

My code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); var   number, zero : Integer; 
begin   // Try to divide an integer by zero - to raise an exception   
    try
        zero   := 0;
        number := 1 div zero;
        ShowMessage('number / zero = '+IntToStr(number));   
    except
        on E : Exception do
            ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : '+E.Message);
    end; 
end;
```

It displays:

[image]

And does not display my ShowMessage.

Comment: IIRC this is just the debugger stepping in *before* your handler. Just continue debugging after pressing OK, and you should see your message. Or turn it off: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32015

Comment: Click OK and press F9, or run your app outside the IDE.

Comment: thank u sir, This is very helpful

Comment: Read your HGTTG and "Don't Panic" :)  .... Click OK, and look where the breakpoint is.